# Rails 4 render partial for nested attributes without loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose I have a form like below

```
<%= form_for @uni, :html => {:multipart => true, :honeypot => true} do |uni_form| %>    
 <% 3.times { @uni.app.build } %>
                  <%= uni_form.fields_for :apps do |builder| %>                    
                      <%= render 'app', uni_form: builder %>
                  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and my app partial is

```
  <div>
    <%= uni_form.label :uni_id, "University" %>
    <%= uni_form.collection_select :uni_id, @unis, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true} %>
  </div>
```

Now I want the first form code without the loop. Something like this

```
 <%= form_for @uni, :html => {:multipart => true, :honeypot => true} do |uni_form| %>    
     <% 3.times { @uni.app.build } %>

<%= render 'app', uni_form: builder %>
<%= render 'app', uni_form: builder %>
<%= render 'app', uni_form: builder %>

    <% end %>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why is this bad? Looks fine to me.

Comment: not working for me. I think I am messing with uni_form and builder

Comment: Maybe it's the fact that you're using `uni_form` as the argument for your `form_for` block and also you're using it as a key in your `render` call.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, *don't build your associated objects in your view - do it in your controller*:

```
#app/controllers/unis_controller.rb
class UnisConstroller < ApplicationController
   def new
      @uni = Uni.new
      3.times do
         @uni.apps.build
      end
   end
end
```

Secondly, the [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) method is your friend here.

You'll gain what you need by using the following:

```
#app/views/unis/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @uni, :html => {:multipart => true, :honeypot => true} do |uni_form| %>    
   <%= uni_form.fields_for :apps do |builder| %>                    
       <%= builder.label :uni_id, "University" %>
       <%= builder.collection_select :uni_id, @unis, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true} %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`fields_for` takes your model's associated objects and automatically creates the fields you need. There is literally no need to "loop" - `fields_for` does it for you... *if you set it up correctly.*

The problem you have is you're building your associated objects at runtime, which is not only inefficient & against convention, but I think it will prevent the `form_for` from recognizing them (which is what allows `fields_for` to loop through them).

The above code should fix this for you.

Comment: well, this not exactly what I need. I want to render the partial 3 times without the loop.

Comment: yes but may be I am confused. I wanted to render partial but you showed without rendering. I am not sure what I am missing here.